# How to insert values from valuable textviews to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I set the retrieved data from mysql to `TextView`, and now I need to insert value from the "valuable textview". I think I need 2 php/api to do that but I don't know how to use it in one activity. it successfully retrieved the value and set it to `TextView`, but fail to send it to mysql.

here's my script :

```
public class ListJawaban extends Activity {
    JSONArray mk = null;


    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView idm, nama_mk, kls;
    Button submit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.spin_main);

            Intent in = getIntent();
            String kode = in.getStringExtra("id_stu");
            String link_url = "http://xxxxxxxx/ffffff/gggggg/mkQuiz.php?kode="+kode;

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

            try {
                mk = json.getJSONArray("mk");

                for(int i = 0; i < mk.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject ar = mk.getJSONObject(i);

                    TextView mhs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nim_mhs);
                    TextView mkname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_mk);
                    TextView kelas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kelas);

                    String mhs_get = ar.getString("id_mhw");
                    String mkname_get = ar.getString("mk_mhw");
                    String kelas_get = ar.getString("kelas");

                    mhs.setText(mhs_get);
                    mkname.setText(mkname_get);
                    kelas.setText(kelas_get);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                        new DataMasuk().execute();
                        Intent forum = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForumActivity.class);                    
                        forum.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(forum);                   
                        finish();
                }
            });
        }

        public class DataMasuk extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            String success;

            String url_link = "http://xxxxxxxx/ffffff/gggggg/postAns.php";

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String strnama = nama_mk.getText().toString();
                String stremail = idm.getText().toString();
                String strpassword = kls.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mk_mhs", strnama));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_mhs", stremail));
                nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", strpassword));

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_link, "POST", nvp);
                try {
                    success = json.getString("success");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return null;
            }



        }
 }
```

and this is the php to insert the value

```
<?php

$id_mhs=$_POST['id_mhs'];
$mk_mhs = $_POST['mk_mhs'];
$kelas=$_POST['kelas'];

include "koneksi.php";


$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_tampung (id_mhs,mk_mhs,kelas)VALUES('$id_mhs','$mk_mhs','$kelas')";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
if($hasil)
    {
    $response["success"] = "1";
        $response["message"] = "Successfully Added";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else
    {$response["success"] = "0";
     $response["message"] = "Sorry somethings wrong";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

but it doesn't work, anyone can help me? its my homework and should be done on Thursday :(

Comment: remove Intent forum = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForumActivity.class);                    
                        forum.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(forum);                   
                        finish(); and start ForumActivity if succes = 1 in doinbackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change

```
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    new DataMasuk().execute();

            }
        });
```

and

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String strnama = nama_mk.getText().toString();
            String stremail = idm.getText().toString();
            String strpassword = kls.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mk_mhs", strnama));
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_mhs", stremail));
            nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kelas", strpassword));

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_link, "POST", nvp);
            try {
                success = json.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1) {

                    Intent forum = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForumActivity.class);                    
                    forum.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(forum);                   
                    finish();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return null;
        }



    }
```

Comment: with this `success = json.getString("success"); if (success == "1") {` it works fine. thanks for ur help sir :)